# Saving a Python File via Atom Results in Module Import Error - Saving from Anywhere Else Causes No Problem

Tags: python, compiler-errors, directory, atom-editor, modulenotfounderror

I recently cloned a github repository (https://github.com/lpbsscientist/YeaZ-GUI.git)  to begin understanding the code and making edits to it. I have set up a conda virtual environment with all the dependencies required and have been running GUI_main.py  successfully via the command line.

In an attempt to gain a better understanding of what the script does, I opened it in Atom and began making edits (not saving them). I inserted several print statements and additional comments. With the path to the virtual environment saved as profile on the Atom script package, I was able to successfully run GUI_main.py from Atom.

So far, so good.

I then saved the current version of GUI_main.py. I tried to run it again, but this time, I got the following error:

`File "GUI_main.py", line 55, in <module> import neural_network as nn ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'neural_network`

I got the same error message running the new saved version of GUI_main.py from the command line, atom, and the python 3.6.8 IDE.

I have made no edits to the file structure in GitHub repo. GUI_main.py is located in the directory YeaZ-GUI. This script imports several modules in the subdirectory YeaZ-GUI/unet, and the script appends their paths correctly (as far as I know - see initialization commands below). GUI_main.py imports numerous modules in the following important statement:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import h5py
import skimage

# For writing excel files
#from openpyxl import load_workbook
#from openpyxl import Workbook

# Import everything for the Graphical User Interface from the PyQt5 library.
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog, QSpinBox,
    QMessageBox, QPushButton, QCheckBox, QAction, QStatusBar, QLabel)
from PyQt5 import QtGui

#Import from matplotlib to use it to display the pictures and masks.
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

#append all the paths where the modules are stored. Such that this script
#looks into all of these folders when importing modules.
sys.path.append("./unet")
sys.path.append("./disk")
sys.path.append("./icons")
sys.path.append("./init")
sys.path.append("./misc")

from PlotCanvas import PlotCanvas

import Extract as extr
from image_loader import load_image
from segment import segment
import neural_network as nn #this is the statement causing the error
```

Curious as to what was going on, I deleted the current version of GUI_main.py and redownloaded the GUI_main.py script from the Github repo mentioned above and placed it into the same location it was before.

This time, I made the same edits via the python IDE, and I was then able to successfully run the script from the command line with no errors.

However, After opening this edited version of the file in Atom and saving it (making no edits), I got the exact same error message as before - after running from Atom as well as the command line.

Interestingly, repeating this same procedure for the neural_network.py module as well as other modules (i.e editing it, saving it in Atom, and then running it) gives no error message.

It seems like the problem is resulting from the action of saving GUI_main.py on Atom? Could this be possible? Please offer any insight.

Comment: I should also note that the import statement causing the problem is the last import statement (import neural network as nn), meaning that all of the other modules were able to imported successfully.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some more experimenting. Turns out that I had downloaded an auto-formatting package (auto pep8) through Atom that was changing the order of my import statements upon saving.

The package's auto-formating moved the `import neural_networks as nn` to a position before the sys.path.append statements and thus the subdirectory unet where neural_network.py is located was not being searched for importable modules.